# EF 6 Future - Any new versions coming out?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm thinking about doing a course on Entity Framework 6 but only if new versions will be coming out. EF Core is a light weight version so it's really different.

Does anyone know if new versions of EF 6 will be coming out or is it all about EF Core now?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a discussion, not a question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [Entity Framework Core 1.1 Plans](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/29/entity-framework-core-1-1-plans/):

> Along with EF Core 1.1, **we are also starting work on the EF6.2 release**